# Conv2D: Keras to Pytorch

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Pretty new to DL and struggling to convert an existing Keras Conv2D model to Pytorch.

This is the original Keras model I need to replicate:

```
def build_model(SHAPE, nb_classes, bn_axis, seed=None):

    if seed:
        np.random.seed(seed)

    input_layer = Input(shape=SHAPE)

    # Step 1
    x = Conv2D(32, 3, 3, init='glorot_uniform', border_mode='same', activation='relu')(input_layer)
    # Step 2 - Pooling
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    # Step 1
    x = Conv2D(48, 3, 3, init='glorot_uniform', border_mode='same', activation='relu')(x)
    # Step 2 - Pooling
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    # Step 1
    x = Conv2D(64, 3, 3, init='glorot_uniform', border_mode='same', activation='relu')(x)
    # Step 2 - Pooling
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

    # Step 1
    x = Conv2D(96, 3, 3, init='glorot_uniform', border_mode='same', activation='relu')(x)
    # Step 2 - Pooling
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

    # Step 3 - Flattening
    x = Flatten()(x)

    # Step 4 - Full connection

    x = Dense(output_dim=256, activation='relu')(x)
    # Dropout
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = Dense(output_dim=2, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(input_layer, x)

    return model
```

And this is my attempt of the Pytorch equivalent:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # conv layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, padding='same')
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 48, 3, padding='same')
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(48, 64, 3, padding='same')
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 96, 3, padding='same')
        # max pooling layer
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # dropout layer (p=0.25)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        # linear layers
        self.fc1 = nn.LazyLinear(256) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # 1
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        # 2
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # 3
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        # 4
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # flattening
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        # add 1st hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # add 2nd hidden layer, with softmax activation function
        x = F.softmax(self.fc2(x))
        return x
```

I actually just got it to run, however I'm unsure if that necessarily means it's correct, could someone please let me know if my model is true to the original one?

The images I'm using are 200x200 RGB.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: hi @pauli, what exactly did you find different? I can spot a few picks, e.g., in the PyTorch assimilation, you should initialize the conv layers with [`torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html#torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_); the padding should be set to `same`; there is no softmax layer applied on the last dense one.

Comment: Hi @ndrwnaguib, thanks for your response. Yes, noticed the padding missing after posting, just added it. Wasn't sure if I could add a softmax layer on the last dense.  Also I'm not sure where/how to add the initializer you suggested, I didn't see that in simpler examples I've seen online. I'm mainly concerned with the numbers, as I don't understand fully how to calculate activations/parameters. Do the numbers I used in the layers make sense to you? (I imagine the first linear layer must be incorrect)

Comment: Hi @ndrwnaguib, I just made more progress (I think!). Added softmax to last dense layer, amended the flattening to flatten all dimensions except batch (that was breaking my code!), and discovered I can use LazyLinear to avoid specifying in_features, so implemented that for the 1st linear layer which I was unsure about. With all these changes, the model ran, and I got interesting results, however I'm not sure if this means all is correct, what do you think? I've edited this on the code on the original post. Thanks! Pau